# Does the velocity of a wave change after being reflected against a moving object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

This problem is from my friend ;

> A man is waiting for a bus. The bus is heading toward him with $v=20\dfrac{km}{h}$
>   To evaluate the duration, the man sent a wave with $f=880Hz$ toward the bus.
>   The wave came back to him after $3.5s$ passed. What was the distance between 
>   the man and the bus? Calculate the wavelength too.

Comment: Is it a light wave?

Comment: I think it is not.

Comment: he should specific, we haven't been given a wave velocity, only a bus velocity

Comment: I guess so, but a wave velocity is not given;;

Comment: I just wonder whether a wave velocity changes or not

Comment: I guess the downvote is because this looks like a [homework question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). However if we we ignore the homework aspects I think it is a perfectly fair question about the physics of sound waves.

Comment: @JohnRennie It does seems homework like, though if this were a homework problem, I wouldn't downvote it. It is useful to others in the future.

Comment: I haven't asked him whether this is a homework or not, but it's not a homework for ME. I just wonder the wave velocity is changed after a reflection or not.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the wave is a sound wave i.e. a compression wave moving through air. The velocity of the wave is determined by the elastic properties of the air. Specifically it is given by:

$$ v = \sqrt{\gamma\frac{P}{\rho}} $$

where $P$ is the air pressure, $\rho$ is the air density and $\gamma$ is a constant called the [adiabatic index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio).

So for any given pressure and density the speed of sound *relative to the air it's passing through* is constant and is not changed when a sound wave reflects off a moving object. What does happen when the wave reflects off a moving object is that the frequency of the wave is changed. This is called the [Doppler shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect).

Comment: So when the wave reflects off the object, the velocity is not changed, but the frequency is changed and so does the wavelength. Am I right?

Comment: @gorani: Correct

Answer (score 1):

> The wave came back to him after 3.5s passed.

That gives a clue as to what kind of signal this was (and wasn't). It wasn't electromagnetic radiation (e.g. light). It was sound.

Sound is a wave carried by a medium, in this case, air. The velocity of the source of a sound has no effect on the velocity of the propagating sound wave. This gives you the information needed to calculate the distance. Multiplying the time by the speed of sound gives the round trip time. Halve that and you get the distance to the bus (at the time the sound reflected off the bus).

While the velocity of the source relative to the air has no effect on the velocity of the sound wave, it does have an effect on the frequency. When you stop at a train crossing, the sound of the train's whistle drops as the train passes in front of you. The velocity of a receiver relative to the air similarly changes the frequency the receiver hears. Both are examples of the Doppler effect.

The moving bus first acts as a receiver. The frequency of the sound hitting the bus will be slightly more than 880 Hz. As the sound reflects off the bus, the bus now acts as a moving source. This increases the frequency of the reflected sound yet more.